# Remove the commas in the double quotes from csv file in UNIX

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a file z.csv and it is csv file. SOme of the rows have double quotes and commas within. I need to remove the commas in the double quotes and then remove the double quotes from each record.

```
"abc","1,234",90,1

,"1,12,000","12,000",RTC

,,,

qqq,www,222,"323"
```

I need output like this,

- Output:

```
abc,1234,90,1

,112000,12000,RTC

,,,

qqq,www,222,323
```

Any help would be appreciated in UNIX!!!

Comment: A proper CSV parser does this automatically.

Comment: Could you pls elaborate?

Comment: I mean, a CSV parser uses the quotes to decide which commas separate fields, and which commas are part of a field. What you are asking is basically, "How do I write a CSV parser?"

Comment: Yes, Sorry, I've never used a CSV parser

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{
    while ( match($0,/"[^"]*"/) ) {
        fld = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
        gsub(/,/,"",fld)
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) fld substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}' file
abc,1234,90,1

,112000,12000,RTC

,,,

qqq,www,222,323
```

If that's not all you need then see [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).

Comment: Thanks so much... Works like a charm.. I will read more about CSV parsing.:)